# Response of an LTI system by convolution

Tags: signal, math, signal-theory

[image]

So here in the picture \$e^{jwt}\$ is the input to the system and \$h(t)\$ is the impulse response. So, by convolution integral shouldn't the response be \$h(t-T)e^{jwT} dT\$? But here it is \$h(T)e^{jw(t-T)}dT\$. What am I missing here?

Comment: If you think of convolution as: fold; slide; multiply; add, (or fold; slide; integrate), it doesn't matter which of the signal or h(t) is folded

Comment: @Chu wow!! That just cleared everything.

Answer (score 1):

In the convolution integral we're used to seeing \$h(t - \tau)\$ when talking about impulse response \$h(t)\$, however:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty{f(\tau)}g(t - \tau)d\tau = \int_{-\infty}^\infty{f(t - \tau)}g(\tau)d\tau $$

In this case the left side is used with \$ f(\tau) = h(\tau)\$ and \$ g(t - \tau) = e^{j\omega_k(t - \tau)}\$ so you have:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty{f(\tau)}g(t - \tau)d\tau = \int_{-\infty}^\infty{h(\tau)}e^{j\omega_k(t - \tau)}d\tau = e^{j\omega_kt}\int_{-\infty}^\infty{h(\tau)}e^{-j\omega_k\tau}d\tau$$

Answer (score 0):

Nothing.  Just do a variable change \$\tau'=t-\tau\$ and you'll get your integral.